# Is the identity permutation a transposition?

Tags: permutations, symmetric-groups

I've heard every permutation can be expressed as a composition of transpositions. How would this be done with the permutation $\pi:\{1\}\to\{1\}$? This only seems possible if one includes the identity as a transposition.

Comment: The identity permutation is most certainly not a transposition, but it is a product of transpositions. What do you get if you multiply a transposition by itself?

Comment: @bof But there are no transpositions on the symmetric group over a singleton.

Comment: By convention an empty product is the multiplicative identity.  Correspondingly the product of no transpositions is the identity permutation (the identity element of any symmetric group).  In any case transpositions have odd parity while the identity map is of even parity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The identity permutation is precisely the composition of *zero* transpositions.

Comment: I don't understand. So the symmetric group on one element can't be generated by transpositions?

Comment: @user3865391 It has zero transpositions, but it has the identity element by **definition** of a group. Indeed it is the trivial group.

Comment: @user3865391: it is generated by the empty set of transpositions.